# Warning: implicit declaration of function ‘malloc’, even if <stdlib.h> is included

Tags: c, list, malloc

This is an extract of a code, where I populate a list with the elements of an array.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "../../lib/kernel/list.h"
#include "./listpop.h"

struct item {
    struct list_elem elem;
    int value;
    int priority;
};

void populate(struct list * l, int * a, int n);

void populate(struct list * l, int * a, int n)
{
  int i = 0;
  while(i != n) {
    struct item * newitem = malloc(sizeof(struct item));
    newitem->value = a[i];
    list_push_back(l,newitem);
    i++;
  }
}

void test_assignment_1()
{   struct list our_list;
    list_init(&our_list);
    populate(&our_list, ITEMARRAY, ITEMCOUNT);
}
```

Code inside list.h:

```
/* List element. */
struct list_elem 
{
  struct list_elem *prev;     /* Previous list element. */
  struct list_elem *next;     /* Next list element. */
};

/* List. */
struct list 
{
  struct list_elem head;      /* List head. */
  struct list_elem tail;      /* List tail. */
};

void list_init (struct list *);
```

Code inside list.c:

```
/* Initializes LIST as an empty list. */
void
list_init (struct list *list)
{
  ASSERT (list != NULL);
  list->head.prev = NULL;
  list->head.next = &list->tail;
  list->tail.prev = &list->head;
  list->tail.next = NULL;
}
```

And finally, the code inside listpop.h:

```
#define ITEMCOUNT 10
int ITEMARRAY[ITEMCOUNT] = {3,1,4,2,7,6,9,5,8,3};
```

Here are the warnings I get:

`warning: implicit declaration of function ‘malloc’`

`warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘malloc’`

So far, all I've read about those warnings is to add stdlib.h, but as you can see from my code I've already done it, and the code still give me those warnings. I've restarted the code many times, so the error lays somewhere in the code.

Anyone knows what is not working here?

Comment: Please include a [mre] in your question. I don't get those warnings, but I do get an error on the undeclared type `struct list_elem`. Most likely the error is in code you haven't shown us.

Comment: Do you get the same error from a [more trivial example](https://godbolt.org/z/9BnKbE)?

Comment: Can you name the compiler and version you're using?

Comment: Have you saved your file before compiling? Is this the exact code in the file? Because it should not behave as you describe.

Comment: Everyone, I've updated the question with more details about the code. Ask me if you need anything else. About the version of the compiler, sadly I have no idea how to retrieve it.

Comment: What lines do the warnings point to?

Comment: I've updated the code, and this is the line where it causes the warning: ../../tests/threads/assignment_1.c:21:33:

Comment: Even if you don't know the version, can you at least give the name of the compiler software are you using?  How did you install it? What OS? What commands do you type/click to compile your program?

Comment: I'll try to be as much detailed as possible!
I use a macOS Mojave. For the compiler, I'm using a terminal (is that the compiler?). I'm running this on a virtual machine (pintos), started with vagrant. There's a section that handles tests on threads functions. The code I provided is from a test of this section, that is supposed to print a list after it is sorted.
Inside in this section, commands to execute code are `make clean` to clear old binaries, and `make` to compile pintos. Make is where I get the warnings.

Comment: I discovered what was wrong. Due to the particular structure of this system I'm working in (it's a school assignment), malloc needs to be imported from a file called malloc.h, in a folder called threads, that contains the declaration of malloc functions. Should I delete the question, since it is unlikely that other users will bump in the same problem?

Comment: @Kyle: it looks like I was almost right after all :)

Comment: It seems to me like you're using an incomplete installation; your C standard library isn't being linked in for whatever reason...

Answer (score 0):

You might be compiling on a obsolete system with a non conforming compiler and/or C library. Try including `<malloc.h>` in addition to `<stdlib.h>` and always include the standard headers first.

Comment: I've added `#include <malloc.h>` to the code at the beginning, but it gives me an error.

Comment: @Kyle: OK, not the correct explanation. Did you move the `#include <stdlib.h>` and other standard headers before the other includes?

Comment: Yes, and it still gives me an error for <malloc.h>. I'm running the code on a virtual machine. Could this be the problem?